# T-SQL query that summarises hourly sales quantity from a sales log table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I’ve got a Sales table than captures sales for items. The (simplified) Sales table has the following columns:

```
[InsertedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ItemCode] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Qty] [float] NULL
```

I need a T-SQL query that returns the total Qty for each ItemCode  within each Hour throughout a day, based on the InsertedDateTime:

, ,  ,

Can I do this with just one query, or do I need to process the data into a 'summary' table first?

Comment: Here is the output I need: YYYYMMDD, HH, ItemCode, Total of Qty for that ItemCode in that HH hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Group by` and `Sum`

```
SELECT [ItemCode],
       [InsertedDateTime],
       Datepart(hour, [InsertedDateTime]) [Hour],
       Sum(qty) Hourly_Total
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY [ItemCode],
          [InsertedDateTime],
          Datepart(hour, [InsertedDateTime])
```

Comment: This is absolutely fine as long as OP doesn't need rows for hours during which no products were sold at all

Comment: @paul - If OP needs total as `0` for those missing `hours` then use a calender or may be `hour` table do a `left join` with that table

Answer (score 0):

Use `CTE` to get the details for every hour.

```
;With CTE AS
(
SELECT 1 AS Cnt
UNION ALL
SELECT Cnt + 1 FROm CTE WHERE cnt + 1 <= 24
)

SELECT A.cnt AS [Hour], B.[ItemCode],
       B.[InsertedDateTime],
       B.Hourly_Total FROM CTE AS A
Left join
(
SELECT [ItemCode],
       [InsertedDateTime],
       Datepart(hour, [InsertedDateTime]) AS [hour],
       Sum(qty) Hourly_Total
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY [ItemCode],
          [InsertedDateTime],
          Datepart(hour, [InsertedDateTime]) 

) AS B
ON A.Cnt = [B.hour]
```

Comment: Not really an issue for only 24 rows, but using a recursive CTE to generate a sequence of numbers does not scale well at all, and is best avoided. Aaron Bertrand has done a good [3 part series on how to generate a set or sequence without a loop](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) that is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
[InsertedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ItemCode] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Qty] [float] NULL
```

)

This stored procedure pass on a string like just the date '2014-2-2'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetQuanitySoldByHours]
 (
      @Date datetime
 )

AS 

BEGIN
Create Table #DayHours  -- A Primary Table just To make the left join
(
   hour bigint
)

Declare @Counter int = 0;

WHILE @Counter <= 23    -- Adding values to temp table in loop
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO #DayHours VALUES (@Counter)
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END



SELECT
    @Date AS DAYDATE
    dh.hour AS DAYHOUR ,
    ISNULL(s.ItemCode,0) AS ITEMCODE,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.Qty),0) AS SOLDQUATITY 
FROM #DayHours dH 
left outer join 
dbo.Sales s 
ON dh.hour = DATEPART(hh,s.InsertedDateTime) 
GROUP BY s.ItemCode, dh.hour

DROP TABLE #DayHours   -- Droping temp table 

END
```

Comment: Using a `WHILE` loop to generate a table of 24 numbers, is [even worse than a recursive CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278721/t-sql-query-that-summarises-hourly-sales-quantity-from-a-sales-log-table/28278976#comment44912450_28278976)

Comment: @GarethD what if i use an identity column in my temp table and just call insert 24 times would that be faster. Plus i read the article is it optimized to generate sequence that way? Any better and most optimized way u can suggest ?

Comment: In all honesty, for 24 rows it really isn't going to make much of a difference either way, my preference is to use the Stacked CTE method ([read more here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)), but as you can see near the bottom of [part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2) the difference between using a numbers table, stacked CTEs, or one of the system tables is not remarkable, so it is really personal preference - Just not a recursive CTE or a while loop.

Comment: For something as small and static as the 24 hours in a day, I would probably just use a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) - `SELECT [Hour] FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)....(23)) t ([Hour])`.